# Does RequireJS loads previously loaded files (.Js or .html) from cache?

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angular-ui-router, require

I am using **requireJs** in my app. I face a scenario and I want to clear it out.
I'm loading the particular template (views) and their dependent js files based on location url or **routes**. See Following code example.

```
routes: {
            '/': {
                templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
                dependencies: [
                    'scripts/controllers/login.js',
                ]
            },
            '/abc-view': {
                templateUrl: 'views/abc.html',
                requireLogin: true,
                dependencies: [
                    'scripts/controllers/abc.js',
                    'scripts/controllers/xyz.js',
                ]
            },
            '/xyz-view': {
                templateUrl: 'views/xyz.html',
                requireLogin: true,
                dependencies: [
                    'scripts/controllers/xyz',
                    }
        }
```

When I change to **xyz** view then **xyz.js** file will be loaded. My question is when I change to **abc** view does the **xyz.js** will be loaded if yes then will it be loaded from cache ?

I have seen in newtwork tab it loads the same file i.e **xyz.js** again, not from cache same with the html templates that are already included in one template with **ng-inlcude** it does not loads from cache.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

flow of my application is as following:
`index.html` have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/requirejs/require.js" data-main="config.js"></script>
```

In `Config.js` I'm manually bootstrapping the app.

```
requirejs.config({

  "paths":{
        "angular": "libs/angular/angular.min",
        "angular-route":"libs/angular-route/angular-route",
        "angular-sanitize":"libs/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize",
        "jquery-ui":"libs/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min",                
        "ngAnimate":"libs/angular-animate/angular-animate.min",
                "angularSrapCore":"libs/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.min",
        "angularStrap":"libs/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.tpl.min"
    },
    "shim": {
            "angular": {
              "exports": "angular"
            },
            "drutasApp": {

                    deps: ["angular", "angular-route","angular-sanitize","jquery-ui","ngAnimate"]

            },
            "angular-route": {
                    deps: ["angular"]
            }
        }
});

require(['angular','app'     
                    ], function (angular) {
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {console.log("app bootstraped");
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
        });
});
```

`app.js` is in same directory with the `config.js`, code is following...

```
define(['scripts/routes.js','scripts/services/dependencyResolverFor.js'], function(config, dependencyResolverFor)
{
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate','ngSanitize']);

    app.config(
    [
        '$routeProvider',
        '$locationProvider',
        '$controllerProvider',
        '$compileProvider',
        '$filterProvider',
        '$provide',

        function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $controllerProvider, $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide)
        {
            app.controller = $controllerProvider.register;
            app.directive  = $compileProvider.directive;
            app.filter     = $filterProvider.register;
            app.factory    = $provide.factory;
            app.service    = $provide.service;
            app.constant   = $provide.constant;

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);

            if(config.routes !== undefined)
            {
                angular.forEach(config.routes, function(route, path)
                {
                    $routeProvider.when(path, {
                        templateUrl:route.templateUrl,
                        resolve:dependencyResolverFor(route.dependencies)
                    });
                });
            }

            if(config.defaultRoutePaths !== undefined)
            {
                $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo:config.defaultRoutePaths});
            }
        }
    ]);

   return app;
});



`routes.js` is as following...

define([], function()
{
    return {
        defaultRoutePath: '/',
        routes: {
            '/': {
                templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
                dependencies: [
                    'scripts/controllers/home'
                ]
            },
            '/abc-view': {
                templateUrl: 'views/abc.html',
                dependencies: [
                    'scripts/controllers/abc',
                    'scripts/controllers/xyz'
                ]
            },
            '/xyz-view': {
                templateUrl: 'views/xyz.html',
                dependencies: [
                    'scripts/controllers/xyz'
                ]
            }
        }
    };
});
```

**dependencyResolver.js**

```
    define([], function()
{
    return function(dependencies)
    {
        var definition =
        {
            resolver: ['$q','$rootScope', function($q, $rootScope)
            {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                require(dependencies, function()
                {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function()
                    {
                        deferred.resolve();
                    });
                });

                return deferred.promise;
            }]
        }

        return definition;
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't know what is that ```dependencies``` property under a route object? All I can do is guessing that you were not using requireJS to load your ```xyz.js``` . Because if being provided such string requireJS will add ```.js``` to the end of the string, therefore you will not able to load ```'scripts/controllers/xyz.js.js'``` . I may able to help you with this question, but I will need more information of what is the name of this ```router``` you are using (doesn't look like ```ui-route``` or ```ng-route``` for me).

Comment: If I didn't add .js extension at the end then there should come error if requireJS is not getting used. If I omit .js extension then there is no issue it is getting loaded.
I'm new to require plz correct if I wrote anything wrong.

Comment: As mention above. ```requireJS``` does not need ```.js``` extension. It will add this extension on its own. ---- **FOR JS FILES** If you are loading js files from requireJS it will not load again that js file ever again. ---- **FOR HTML FILE** requireJS has nothing to do with this, but angular. And the behavior will be the same. HTML view will be reuse without trigger any HTTP request.

Comment: But when I checks in network tab it does not show the same file (i.e previously loaded) from cache instead it shows the size of file and the same time in which it was loaded previously.

Comment: Yes, that is why I asked what is the ```router``` you are using? Because it doesn't look like you are using requireJS at all. I need your real code, js files as much as possible to provide you an answer.

Comment: I am using ng-route.

Comment: @Linh Pham, I have given full overview, plz look into it.

Comment: It is almost enough. Can you provide `dependencyResolverFor.js` content. That is the last piece I needed for now.

Comment: I have edited in question. Plz check.

Answer (score -1):

---

> My question is when I change to **abc** view does the **xyz.js** will be loaded

No, `requireJS` will judge on the final `URL` of the script tag going to be fetched. If it is already loaded before, `requireJS` won't do anything.

---

> if yes then will it be loaded from cache ?

Not likely cache got to be used, but `requireJS` simply detect if the same file with same `URL` got loaded before or not. If it is loaded before, `requireJS` will just execute your js without loading anything.

---

> I have seen in newtwork tab it loads the same file i.e xyz.js again, not from cache same with the html templates that are already included in one template with ng-inlcude it does not loads from cache.

As looking into your code, `requireJS` got to use to fetching the dependencies. And this behavior cannot happen, unless `requirejs.undef()` got called somewhere. Or that is an old version of `requireJS` where module's `URL` was not tracking and `<script>` got to be loaded regardless the conditions.

---

*NOTE I am not sure about the behavior of older version than 2.1.x of `requireJS`.*

Comment: My Question is, suppose I'm on **abc** view, then I go to **xyz** view and when I refresh the page form browser will it load abc.js file or not ?

Comment: When a `reload/refresh` of page involed. No, `requireJS` does not have anything to do with cache. You will need to do it at server side.

Comment: Is threre any way to implement it...?

Comment: I am not really sure what you are asking but it can be done with the `response headers`. I done it once for my application with `ETag` and `Last-Modified`. Also it is depends on what running at your sever side, e.g. Apache... etc... ---- Regardless, `requireJS` has nothing to do with browser's cache.

Comment: I'm asking, lets suppose I'm on **abc view** and their dependencies `JS` files are `abc.js` . Then I go to **xyz view**  whose dependencies `JS` files are `xyz.js` . When  I reload the page `xyz.js` loads successfully but I also wants to be load `abc.js` file as well since in this view (**xyz view**) I also need **abc.js** file.

Comment: `'/abc-view': {
                templateUrl: 'views/abc.html',
                dependencies: [
                    'scripts/controllers/abc'
                ]
            },
            '/xyz-view': {
                templateUrl: 'views/xyz.html',
                dependencies: [
                    'scripts/controllers/xyz'
                ]
            }`

Comment: Man, you keep changing your question... ---- OK, accodring to your latest comments. At `xyz` view, why don't you also add `abc.js` dependency (because you needed it)